# Sum rows per person with two IDs

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with people and one with values. Each person can have two IDs and I need the values assigned to their IDs in the second table to sum with each other (so all of ID1's values would be a single value that is also combined with ID2's values).

```
Table a
ID  ID2 FName
1   4   Jacob
56  13  John

Table b
ID  AID V1  V2
1   4   50  25
2   13  30  0
3   1   10  15
4   4   0   5

Goal output
SUM(V1,V2)  a.ID    a.ID2   FName
105         1       4       Jacob
30          56      13      John
```

I was able to get the value from one ID with

```
SELECT SUM(V1,V2) AS Total, AID, FName
FROM a,b
WHERE b.AID=a.ID
GROUP BY AID
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

I'm guessing I need a subquery to do both at once, but I wasn't sure how to work it in.

Comment: Is the first sum value is 105 or 80?

Comment: 105, because it's record 1, 3 and 4 combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    sum(b.V1 + b.V2) as Total,
    a.ID,
    a.ID2,
    a.FName
from
    a
    inner join b on
        a.ID = b.AID
        or a.ID2 = b.AID
group by
    a.ID,
    a.ID2,
    a.FName;
```

Does this work? I don't have a way to test it right now.

Comment: It should actually be `a.ID=b.AID` but otherwise, yes. Thanks!

Comment: Darn - I must've edited b.AID to b.ID accidentally while correctly editing a.ID1 to a.ID. Somewhat confusing names you have there. :P You're welcome